# Front end development animation effects

Tags: animation, web-frontend

This is a maybe a newbish question that has been aching at me for years.
How do they create moving effects on a background still image? Like fog over a landscape or burning ashes that pop out over a fire. I can't seem to put my finger on it

1)
Moving fog
https://demos.creative-tim.com/paper-kit-2-angular/home?_ga=2.22558072.253694515.1544816132-452414653.1544816132

2)
Moving light effect where there are fire bits flying around at the edge of a blade, it almost jumps out of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moving fog is just this image being animated across the screen:
https://demos.creative-tim.com/paper-kit-2-angular/assets/img/clouds.png

I don't believe I see the other effect you are talking about.

Comment: I can't find it, it was blizzard entertainment, a gaming company, used to always do these things when they create a new website for pre-orders. It was like that for all the world of warcraft expansions. They even had a background with a character (illidan) breathing slightly. Was amazing. Oh and thank you for the answer